# zeppelin giving error in pyspark interpreter for dynamic input

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am not able to get the dynamic input in pyspark from zeppelin context.
This is what I do

%pyspark
z.input("name")

It gives me this error
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark.py", line 162, in 
    eval(compiledCode)
  File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: 'PyZeppelinContext' object has no attribute 'input'**

I am able to execute the statements in the %spark interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

ZeppelinContext is automatically created and injected into Scala language backend, from: http://zeppelin-project.org/docs/zeppelincontext.html

Are you sure that Python can use the Zeppelin Context?

Comment: Yes Pyspark uses the same zeppelin context as stated by the documentation of Zeppelin. I have found a work around for this. I am using z.put("x", "y") to put value to a variable from %spark interpreter and then reading it from %pyspark interpreter. There is I guess some regression for pyspark on this.